# Mootools: Add input text field

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am using the mootools framework to add text inputs to a form. Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/dazaweb/wjMJt/2/

As you can see, the input field appears for a sec, then disappears. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clicking on a submit button which will POST the form. Change the input type to `button` and it will work. Or you can prevent the default behaivor if you still want to use a submit button.

Here is a working link with a button insteed of submit:

http://jsfiddle.net/wjMJt/3/

You can also prevent the default behavoir by cancel the bubbling.

Just add `e.stop();` inside your function, and pass the event argument as a variable named e like this:

```
$('btnAddOption').addEvent('click', function(e) {
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wjMJt/6/

Answer (score 0):

add this in the javascript code

```
event.stop();
```

also pass event in the event handler

```
$('btnAddOption').addEvent('click', function(event) {
```

as by default the button supposed to submit the form which it is doing, but by doing event.stop we are preventing it to submit the form

My bad i wrote jquery ....updated it to javascript

Comment: jQuery? He's using [tag:mootools].

Comment: no i think $ can be used by different libraries as well.... not compulsorily jQuery......that's y jQuery has the noConflict function....in the fiddle provided this is how its coded....

Comment: Other libraries can, and do, use the `$`, but you, and this is a quote, say: "add this in the jquery code..." which is why I left that question.